# EF Core 2.2 LINQ query not working in EF Core 3.0

Tags: entity-framework, ef-core-3.0

Below code works fine at EF Core 2.2 bu not working on EF core 3.0

```
 var items = (from asset in Context.Assets
              join assetCategory in Context.AssetCategories on asset.CategoryId equals assetCategory.Id
              group assetCategory by assetCategory.Id into assetCategories
              select new AssetCategorySummary
              {
                  CategoryId = assetCategories.Key,
                  CategoryName = assetCategories.Select(p => p.CategoryName).FirstOrDefault(),
                  TotalAsset = assetCategories.Count()
              }).ToListAsync();
```

the error I am getting:

> Processing of the LINQ expression 'AsQueryable(Select<AssetCategory, string>(
> source: NavigationTreeExpression
> Value: default(IGrouping<Guid, AssetCategory>)
> Expression: (Unhandled parameter: e),
> selector: (p) => p.CategoryName))' by 'NavigationExpandingExpressionVisitor'
> failed. This may indicate either a bug or a limitation in EF Core.
> See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101433 for more detailed information.

need help please

Comment: This is not a question. Expect changes when upgrading to EF core 3. No need to report them here unless there's an actual question related to it.

Comment: @S. Aziz Kazdal Yes! this is what I told you `fetch the data into memory and then make your query` and although its not effective because this will cost performance or fail in case of huge data.

Comment: @TanvirArjel well need an extra way to do this. Is there something to write raw sql to database ? not entity. something `Context.Database.RawSql`

Comment: @S.AzizKazdal You you can write raw sql and the use `FromSql` method. For more details : https://entityframeworkcore.com/querying-data-raw-sql-queries

Comment: @TanvirArjel no FromSql it's not what I ment. I want to execute this query and get values to list .
`select Kategori.Id,Kategori.CategoryName,count(Varlik.Id) as [Varlık Sayısı] from Assets Varlik inner join AssetCategories Kategori on Kategori.Id = Varlik.CategoryId group by Kategori.Id,Kategori.CategoryName`

Comment: After your revision: what I meant is `GroupBy(p => new { p.Id, p.CategoryName })`.

Comment: @S.AzizKazdal that's no solution. The original query had a problem but EF Core hid it from you. Client-side evaluation is a performance killer that wasn't available in EF 6.2 and shouldn't have appeared in EF Core at all. You need to change the *original* query.

Comment: First of all, you shouldn't be using joins. It's the ORM's (EF's) job to create the joins from entity relations. Second, `FirstOrDefault()` has no equivalent aggregate function in SQL. Even in SQL, if you wanted the category name you'd have grouped by `CategoryID, CategoryName` or joined with the lookup table *after* the `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 16):

This is due to one of the [breaking changes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-3.0/breaking-changes)  in **EF Core 3.0** and that is: [LINQ queries are no longer evaluated on the client](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-3.0/breaking-changes#linq-queries-are-no-longer-evaluated-on-the-client)

So write the query in such way that EF Core can convert the expression into T-SQL or  fetch the data into memory and then make your query.

Comment: Automatic client evaluation is gone completely though - it's not an option and cannot be enabled.

Comment: Yeah, see **Mitigations** section in the second link - *If a query can't be fully translated, then either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or use AsEnumerable(), ToList(), or similar to explicitly bring data back to the client where it can then be further processed using LINQ-to-Objects.* As you can see there is no option for enabling it. Also `QueryClientEvaluationWarning` is marked as `[Obsolete("Automatic client evaluation is no longer supported. This event is no longer generated.")]`

Comment: I don't get this breaking change. Even a simple group by fails now that used to work in ef 2.x

Answer (score 16):

The original query had problems but EF Core hid it under the carpet, slowing everything down.

Client-side evaluation was evil when it was introduced in LINQ to SQL and removed in Entity Framework. I can't think why people though it would be a good idea to add it back to EF Core, but it's a good thing it's gone now. The original query wouldn't run in EF 6.2 either.

The original query needs a bit of fixing, which will probably result in performance improvements. First of all, it's the ORM's job to generate joins from relations and navigation properties.

Second, even in SQL it's impossible to add a field in the SELECT clause that isn't part of `GROUP BY` or an aggregate. There's no aggregate function equivalent to `FirstOrDefault()` unless one uses a windowing function.

To get the category name in SQL, we'd have to either include it in GROUP BY or use a CTE/subquery to group by ID and then look up the category name, eg :

```
SELECT CategoryID,CategoryName,Count(*)
FROM Assets inner join AssetCategories on CategoryID=AssetCategories.ID
GROUP BY CategoryID,CategoryName
```

or

```
SELECT CategoryID,CategoryName,Cnt
FROM (select CategoryID, Count(*) as Cnt
      from Assets
      group by CategoryID) a 
INNER JOIN AssetCategories on CategoryID=AssetCategories.ID
```

The equivalent of the first query in LINQ would be :

```
 var items = (from asset in Context.Assets
              join assetCategory in Context.AssetCategories on asset.CategoryId equals assetCategory.Id
              group asset by new {assetCategory.Id,assetCategory.CategoryName} into summary
              select new AssetCategorySummary
              {
                  CategoryId   = summary.Key.Id,
                  CategoryName = summary.Key.Name,
                  TotalAsset   = summary.Count()
              }).ToListAsync();
```

If the entities are modified so eg Asset has an Category property, the query could be reduced to :

```
 var items = (from asset in Context.Assets
              group asset by new {asset.Category.Id,asset.Category.CategoryName} into summary
              select new AssetCategorySummary
              {
                  CategoryId   = summary.Key.Id,
                  CategoryName = summary.Key.Name,
                  TotalAsset   = summary.Count()
              }).ToListAsync();
```

This need some testing though to ensure it creates a sane query. There have been some surprises in the past and I haven't had the time to check the generated SQL in the final EF Core 3.0

**Update**

LINQPad 6 can use EF Core 3 and even generates a DbContext from a database using the foreign key constraints.

This query

```
 var items = (from asset in Context.Assets
              group asset by new {asset.Category.Id,asset.Category.CategoryName} into summary
              select new AssetCategorySummary
              {
                  CategoryId   = summary.Key.Id,
                  CategoryName = summary.Key.Name,
                  TotalAsset   = summary.Count()
              }).ToListAsync();
```

generates a nice SQL query :

```
SELECT [a0].[ID] AS [CategoryId], [a0].[CategoryName], COUNT(*) AS [TotalAsset]
FROM [Assets] AS [a]
INNER JOIN [AssetCategories] AS [a0] ON [a].[CategoryID] = [a0].[ID]
GROUP BY [a0].[ID], [a0].[CategoryName]
```

Using `join` generates the same SQL query.

Answer (score 6):

you can still perform any sort of set operation on the client via client evaluation  simply insert an `AsEnumerable()` before performing your set operation. This is how all set operations were handled in pre-3.0 versions, and depending on the exact use case client evaluation may perform just as well as server evaluation.