# EF Core 5 with Sum

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

Repost model class:

```
public class TransactionDayReport
{
    public Decimal TotalAmount { get; set; }
    public ICollection<TransactionResponse> TransactionResponses { get; set; } = null!;
}
```

This is my repository method

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<Transaction>> SearchTransactionAsync(SearchTransaction search)
{
    var query = _context.Transactions
                        .Include(t => t.Branch)
                        .Include(t => t.Customer)
                        .AsQueryable();    

    if (search.CIN != null)               
        query = query.Where(t => t.Customer.CIN.Contains(search.CIN));

    if (search.ValueDate != null)
        query = query.Where(t => t.ValueDate.Date == search.ValueDate.Date);

    return await query.ToListAsync();
}
```

Service method:

```
public async Task<TransactionResponse> SearchTransactions(SearchTransaction search)
{
    var transactionList = await _unitOfWork.Transactions.SearchTransactionAsync(search);
    var mapped = ObjectMapper.Mapper.Map<TransactionDayReport>(transactionList);
    return mapped;
}
```

I need to send total amount in service class..

[am looking similar to this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58861477/ef-core-3-0-sumasync-triggers-aggregate-function-exception)

But I am confused how to get addition sum added to my dto. Please can anyone suggest a solution? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way to *also calculate the sum on the DB* is to run another query on the DB, unless the DB query can be re-written to return both the sum and the data.

If you're ok with calculating the Sum on the client, it's more straightforward. Here are some options I could think of:

1. You could configure the mapper to set the sum.
2. You could set the sum after performing the mapping in `SearchTransactions()`.
3. You could change the DTO to calculate the Sum (in which case it wouldn't be a POCO anymore, but I think this is a reasonable approach too):

   ```cs
   public class TransactionDayReport
   {
       private decimal? _totalAmount = null;
       public decimal TotalAmount { get {
           if(_totalAmount is not null) return _totalAmount; // new C# 9 feature :)
           _totalAmount = // calculate total amount here
           return _totalAmount;
       }
       public ICollection<TransactionResponse> TransactionResponses { get; set; } = null!;
   }
   ```

Comment: The only way to also calculate the sum on the DB is to run another query on the DB, unless the DB query can be re-written to return both the sum and the data.---- How to include sum in ef core?

Comment: @Glen if you *really* want to run another query against the db... you can do a `query.Sum(t => t.PropertyYouWantTheSumOf)` in `SearchTransactionAsync()`